# How can I fix Bixby Studio Simulator error?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPLHO.png)

I tried many times, but I couldn't find an answer about unknown error. Does anyone know about this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This would require closer investigation with your specific experience by the developer support team.

Please experience the error again, generate a diagnostics report using the "Create Diagnostics Report" option in Bixby Studio's Help dropdown menu, and reach out to bixby-support@samsung.com with the diagnostics report attached.

Answer (score 0):

@dartbird - please make sure to visit the Developer Console - https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/console and ensure that you register your namespace and capsule (based on the screenshot it should be "dartbird" for your namespace and "hooks" for your capsule.

If you are just trying to test how it works, create your capsule using playground.*name_of_your_capsule

I hope this helps! :)